# Crashing on 10.7, but works on 10.6, possible memory problems

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, osx-lion

I have project that is crashing on very different execution points when compiled in 4.2 on Lion but it works perfectly on 10.6.
Projects Setting shows that Garbage collector is Supported and there are a LOT of objects being autoreleased on all sorts of places without single NSAutoreleasePool instantiated. Could that be a problem?
I couldn't find anything definite with Instruments...

Comment: crashing how? EXC_BAD_ACCESS ? On which line? you don't have autoreleasepool around NSApplication ?

Comment: @Marek Yes, there is exec_bad_access and as I have written, there is no explicit autorelease pool instantiated. Still, as far as I know, there doesn't have to be any. It can crash on very different lines, doesn't have any point of showing soemthing that is proven casual. I wonder if anybody experienced something similar upgrading to 10.7. It is really not necessary to downgrade the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more details, it appears to be a memory corruption issue, that bombs out with the ASLR feature in 10.7.  Enabling zombies (search documents for NSZombie) and stack smash protection might help to track down the problem

Comment: this is what I have presumed as well. I will try zombies. Thanks.